# Browser "back" button doesn't work as it should

Tags: angularjs, firefox, safari, navigation, back-button

I have a weird problem with a browser "**back**" button in *Firefox* and *Safari*.
The thing is, that if I enter a website home page, then click on any link in navigation, and then press the "back" button, it throws me not on a home page, where I previously was, but on a browser's start page.
It works normally, if I navigate for example from "**shop**" to "**about us**" section and then press **back**,

but when scenario is like: **shop -> home -> about us -> back**,  it throws me on a "**shop**", not on "**home**"

in *Chrome*, *Opera*, IE11, Edge it works as it should, only *Safari* and *Firefox* have such problem.
I am using *Angular JS*, the back-end is built on *WordPress*.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hi David. Please post the code that is causing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Does the app use HTML5 mode or legacy mode?

Answer (score 0):

Its with SPA I guess.Also, you cannot touch the `back button`, since it is not on DOM . However, you can check for the web browser and you can create your own button function and provide functionality like :
  [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)
 and then use :

```
 function goBack() {
   window.history.back();
 }
```

Comment: The problem is not in creating custom button, it wouldn't be a problem, 
I can't understand, why browser's history doesn't save home page in it's state.

Comment: Here is a website so you can reproduce it by yourself
https://www.josua-dienst.org/

Comment: Okay, I understand your issue. Not entirely sure what is happening, since if you do `window.history.back()` it works just fine but otherwise, it doesn't.Kindly post the code.@ДавидСергеев